# Tokenise Words into an Array via Regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have the following address:

> 1330 City Street, PO BOX 444 --- Parts 7,8,9, and 13,~~~Centre Wellington Township (Village of Elora),
>   County of Wellington

I would like to tokenise each word that comes ends with comma. In the above example we'll tokenise the following:

**1330 City Street

PO BOX 444 --- Parts 7

8

9

and 13

~~~Centre Wellington Township (Village of Elora)**

I would like to do it in ruby. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one can be handy too. Its removing the last token after comma, and then performs the splitting.

```
input = '1330 City Street, PO BOX 444 --- Parts 7,8,9, and 13,~~~Centre Wellington Township (Village of Elora), County of Wellington'
print input.gsub(/[^,]*$/, "").split(/,/)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
s = "1330 City Street, PO BOX 444 --- Parts 7,8,9, and 13,~~~Centre Wellington Township (Village of Elora), County of Wellington"

s.split(',').last.strip # => "County of Wellington"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do as below :

```
s = "1330 City Street, PO BOX 444 --- Parts 7,8,9, and 13,~~~Centre Wellington Township (Village of Elora), County of Wellington"
s.scan(/[^,]+(?=[,])/).map(&:strip)
# => ["1330 City Street",
#     "PO BOX 444 --- Parts 7",
#     "8",
#     "9",
#     "and 13",
#     "~~~Centre Wellington Township (Village of Elora)"]
puts s.scan(/[^,]+(?=[,])/).map(&:strip)

# >> 1330 City Street
# >> PO BOX 444 --- Parts 7
# >> 8
# >> 9
# >> and 13
# >> ~~~Centre Wellington Township (Village of Elora)
```

Check this out also in [*Rubular.com*](http://rubular.com/r/qXxGjmjx9t)